# How to make servo Dynamixel motor to move from 0 --> 90 --> 180 --> 220--->0 degrees

Tags: python-2.7, ros, servo

Hello software developers.
I am new in programming and ROS. I am working now with servo motors and want to make the controlling node to rotate motor into some degrees like from 0 --> 90--> 180-->0 degrees.
there is a main code and I would like to add def function into the main node:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
from controller_motor.msg import Motor
from controller_motor.srv import Motor2


if os.name == 'nt':
    import msvcrt
    def getch():
        return msvcrt.getch().decode()
else:
    import sys, tty, termios
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    def getch():
        try:
            tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
        return ch

from dynamixel_sdk import *                    # Uses Dynamixel SDK library


class DynamixelController(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #print("1")

        self.motor_sub = rospy.Subscriber("/motor_topic", Motor, self.motor_callback)
        self.test_motor_client(1)                #here we can put request order as 1 for the using id=14 and position= 1500; or as 2 is id same and position is 2500. The cases could be found in the server.py node
    
    def motor_callback(self, data):
        _id = data.id
        _position = data.position

        print("_id : {0}, _position : {1}".format(_id, _position))
        self.read_write(_id, _position)

    def test_motor_client(self, request):
        print("2")
        rospy.wait_for_service('test_motor_service')
        try:
            proxy = rospy.ServiceProxy('test_motor_service', Motor2)
            response = proxy(request)
            print("response is id : {} position : {}".format(response.id, response.position))

            self.read_write(response.id, response.position)

        except rospy.ServiceException as e:
            print("Service call failed: %s"%e)

    def new_rotation(self, response):
        print("3")
        rospy.wait_for_service('test_mototr_rotation')
        try:
            proxy = rospy.ServiceProxy('test_motor_rotation', Motor2)
            response = proxy(request)
            self.read_write(response.id, response.position(arg[0]))
            sleep(2)
            self.read_write(response.id, response._position(arg[1]))
            sleep(2)
            self.read_write(response.id, response._position(arg[2]))
            sleep(2)
        except rospy.ServiceException as e:
            print("Service call failed: %s"%e)
    

    
    def read_write(self, _id, _position):
        print("Start the node")
     

        # Control table address
        ADDR_PRO_TORQUE_ENABLE      = 64                  # Control table address is different in Dynamixel model
        ADDR_PRO_GOAL_POSITION      = 116
        ADDR_PRO_PRESENT_POSITION   = 132
       
        # Protocol version
        PROTOCOL_VERSION            = 2.0                 # See which protocol version is used in the Dynamixel

        # Default setting
        DXL_ID                      = _id                 # Dynamixel ID : 14
        BAUDRATE                    = 1000000             # Dynamixel default baudrate : 1000000
        DEVICENAME                  = '/dev/ttyUSB0'      # Check which port is being used on your controller
                                                          # ex) Windows: "COM1"   Linux: "/dev/ttyUSB0" Mac: "/dev/tty.usbserial-*"

        TORQUE_ENABLE               = 1                 # Value for enabling the torque
        TORQUE_DISABLE              = 0                 # Value for disabling the torque
        DXL_MINIMUM_POSITION_VALUE  = 10                # Dynamixel will rotate between this value
        DXL_MAXIMUM_POSITION_VALUE  = _position         # The position here is already in the degree measurement; and this value (note that the Dynamixel would not move when the position value is out of movable range. Check e-manual about the range of the Dynamixel you use.)
        DXL_MOVING_STATUS_THRESHOLD = 20                # Dynamixel moving status threshold
        

        index = 0
        dxl_goal_position = [DXL_MINIMUM_POSITION_VALUE, DXL_MAXIMUM_POSITION_VALUE]         # Goal position
        


        # Initialize PortHandler instance
        # Set the port path
        # Get methods and members of PortHandlerLinux or PortHandlerWindows
        portHandler = PortHandler(DEVICENAME)

        # Initialize PacketHandler instance
        # Set the protocol version
        # Get methods and members of Protocol1PacketHandler or Protocol2PacketHandler
        packetHandler = PacketHandler(PROTOCOL_VERSION)

        # Open port
        if portHandler.openPort():
            print("Succeeded to open the port")
        else:
            print("Failed to open the port")
            print("Press any key to terminate...")
            getch()
            quit()


        # Set port baudrate
        if portHandler.setBaudRate(BAUDRATE):
            print("Succeeded to change the baudrate")
        else:
            print("Failed to change the baudrate")
            print("Press any key to terminate...")
            getch()
            quit()

        # Enable Dynamixel Torque
        dxl_comm_result, dxl_error = packetHandler.write1ByteTxRx(portHandler, DXL_ID, ADDR_PRO_TORQUE_ENABLE, TORQUE_ENABLE)
        if dxl_comm_result != COMM_SUCCESS:
            print("%s" % packetHandler.getTxRxResult(dxl_comm_result))
        elif dxl_error != 0:
            print("%s" % packetHandler.getRxPacketError(dxl_error))
        else:
            print("Dynamixel has been successfully connected")

        while 1:
            print("Press any key to continue! (or press ESC to quit!)")
            if getch() == chr(0x1b):
                break

            # Write goal position
            dxl_comm_result, dxl_error = packetHandler.write4ByteTxRx(portHandler, DXL_ID, ADDR_PRO_GOAL_POSITION, dxl_goal_position[index])
            if dxl_comm_result != COMM_SUCCESS:
                print("%s" % packetHandler.getTxRxResult(dxl_comm_result))
            elif dxl_error != 0:
                print("%s" % packetHandler.getRxPacketError(dxl_error))

            while 1:
                # Read present position
                dxl_present_position, dxl_comm_result, dxl_error = packetHandler.read4ByteTxRx(portHandler, DXL_ID, ADDR_PRO_PRESENT_POSITION)
                if dxl_comm_result != COMM_SUCCESS:
                    print("%s" % packetHandler.getTxRxResult(dxl_comm_result))
                elif dxl_error != 0:
                    print("%s" % packetHandler.getRxPacketError(dxl_error))

                print("[ID:%03d] GoalPos:%03d  PresPos:%03d" % (DXL_ID, dxl_goal_position[index], dxl_present_position))

                if not abs(dxl_goal_position[index] - dxl_present_position) > DXL_MOVING_STATUS_THRESHOLD:
                    break

            # Change goal position
            if index == 0:
                index = 1
            else:
                index = 0


        # Disable Dynamixel Torque
        dxl_comm_result, dxl_error = packetHandler.write1ByteTxRx(portHandler, DXL_ID, ADDR_PRO_TORQUE_ENABLE, TORQUE_DISABLE)
        if dxl_comm_result != COMM_SUCCESS:
            print("%s" % packetHandler.getTxRxResult(dxl_comm_result))
        elif dxl_error != 0:
            print("%s" % packetHandler.getRxPacketError(dxl_error))

        # Close port
        portHandler.closePort()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('read_write', anonymous=True)
    controller = DynamixelController()
```

and here is the server node:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from controller_motor.srv import Motor2, Motor2Response


def motor_info(req):
    print("receive the request : {}".format(req.order))
    if req.order == 1:
        _id = 14
        #_position = 1500
        _positiondegree = 180                 # change it degree value
        _position = (11.4 * (_positiondegree))  # here is using there 11.4 the number which helps rotate the motor in the correct degree; We get the number encoder number/degree we want to rotate the motor.
              
    elif req.order == 2:
        _id = 14
        #_position = 2047.5
        _positiondegree = 180
        _position = (11.4 * (_positiondegree))
       

    print("Response to this request id : {} and postiion : {}".format(_id, _position))
    return Motor2Response(_id, _position)
   

    
def motor_info_server():

    rospy.init_node('test_motor_service')
    s = rospy.Service('test_motor_service', Motor2, motor_info)
    print("Ready to response some id and position")

    # spin() simply keeps python from exiting until this node is stopped
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    motor_info_server()
```

Now when running the motor it rotates to the degree I would like it to rotate. And now I would like to know how could I give some degrees to make motor rotates from 0 to some other degrees and go back to the 0 degree position again.

I guess there might be applied the list and args for some degrees. But I am not well-known how I could do this :)
I would like to get some advice from professionals like you ,guys :)

I know my question could be obvious for professionals. I would like to get experience in the programming and ROS as much as I can :)

I will be so thankful  for any help and advise how I could do this :)

Thank to everyone who will share his/her idea:)

I wish you have a good day :)

Comment: I don't know much about ROS, but as a general tip - you've posted too much code. I would estimate that at least 90% of the code you show have nothing to do with the issue (motor rotation). Chances of getting an answer improve if you cut down the code sample to the minimum ([mcve]). Usually that means rewriting it from scratch so it does *nothing but* the thing you have a question about.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a new function to your code in the client file:

```
def rotate_bot(self,degree):
     rospy.wait_for_service('rotate_motor')
     try:
         proxy = rospy.ServiceProxy('test_motor_rotation', Motor2)
         response = proxy(degree)
     except rospy.ServiceException as e:
         print("Service call failed: %s"%e)
```

This function basically calls a Service and gives him the amount of degrees the robot has to turn. Also add this function to call the roate function:

```
def test_rotate(self):
       rotate_bot(90)
       rotate_bot(90)
       rotate_bot(-180)
```

Now the robot turns from 0 --> 90 --> 180 --> 0
In your server file you have to add the service in the `motor_info_server()` method:

```
s = rospy.Service('test_motor_rotation', Motor2, rotate_motor)
```

and also add the method:

```
def rotate_motor(req):
    print("received the request : {}".format(req.order))
    degree = req.order
    _id = 14
    _positiondegree = degree                 
    _position = (11.4 * (_positiondegree))  

    return Motor2Response(_id, _position)
```

If you want to pass doubles as degrees you have to change your message datatype from Motor2 to something else...